# Is the inverse of the criterion of fully-faithfulness of derived tensor product also true?

Tags: ct.category-theory, derived-categories, differential-graded-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be differential graded algebras over a field $k$ and $D(A)$ and $D(B)$ be the derived categories of differential graded modules.

Let $N$ be an $A$-$B$ bimodule. Then $(-)\otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_A N$ gives a triangulated functor $D(A)\to D(B)$. It is well-known that we have the follow result. See [Stack Project Tag 09R9, Lemma 22.24.6](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09R9) .

Assume

1. $N$ defines a compact object of $D(B)$;
2. The map $H^i(A)\to \text{Hom}_{D(B)}(N,N[i])$ is an isomorphism for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $(-)\otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_A N$ is a fully faithful functor.

I would like to know whether the inverse statement is true. In more details, if we assume that $N$ defines a compact object of $D(B)$ and $(-)\otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_A N: D(A)\to D(B)$ is fully faithful, is it true that  $H^i(A)\to \text{Hom}_{D(B)}(N,N[i])$ is an isomorphism for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Isn't $H^i(A)=\mathrm{Hom}_{D(A)}(A,A[i])$, so the claim follows immediately from full faithfulness (without even the compactness of $N$)?

Comment: @DenisNardin Oh yes that's so obvious. Thank you.